# how to subset a datafrom with partial match column names

Tags: r

I have a big data frame. I would like to subset the data frame with a list of names that partially match the front part of some column names. I don't know how to write the code.
For example, the list names: `lst <-  c("LD08.1593","LD09.10917","LD10.10226","M05.353086","Thore")`

the data frame columns: 
`...,"LC10096.2", "LD08.1593.s1", "LD08.1593.s2","LD08.1692.1","LD08.1692.2","LD09.10917.s1","LD09.10917.s2","LD10.10226-s1","LD10.10226-s2","LEC.12.6056.70","LEC.12.6113.02","M05.353086","Thore_t1","Thore_t5", ...`
I expect the subset data frame only includes `"LD08.1593.s1","LD08.1593.s2","LD09.10917.s1","LD09.10917.s2","LD10.10226-s1","LD10.10226-s2","M05.353086","Thore_t1","Thore_t5"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try

```
 dat[,grep(paste0("^",paste(lst, collapse="|")), colnames(dat))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:25,14*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=14))

colnames(dat) <- c("LC10096.2", "LD08.1593.s1", "LD08.1593.s2","LD08.1692.1",
"LD08.1692.2","LD09.10917.s1","LD09.10917.s2","LD10.10226-s1",
"LD10.10226-s2","LEC.12.6056.70","LEC.12.6113.02","M05.353086",
"Thore_t1","Thore_t5")

lst <- c("LD08.1593","LD09.10917","LD10.10226","M05.353086","Thore")
```